# can't hide overflow of my sun animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, gsap

I want to make a sunrise and sunset animation at the bottom of the screen. The starting point should be outside the viewport and slowly move to the center-middle and then slowly move beyond the egde of the screen in the bottom right while smoothly moving on top of all other html content.

https://codepen.io/imaginfox/pen/oqqpLK

My problem is that when it leaves the screen a vertical scrollbar appears. 
Also The path of the sun is a bit off as it is not centered in the middle of the viewport, I thought using percent values instead of X and Y pixel values would make it responsive e.g. mobile friendly.

CSS:

```
#sun {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  left: 0%;
  top: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.4/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="sun"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">


    TweenMax.to("#sun", 5, {
        bezier: {
            type: "soft",
            values: [
                { left: "0%", top: "0%" },
                { left: "100%", top: "100%" },
            ]},

        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        repeat:-1,
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a pseudo-element so it'll be contained within `#sun`, which can be placed as you wish, with `overflow: hidden;` to avoid anything creating scrollbars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `overflow: hidden;` on container element

**UPDATED**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NYYORO
wrapper should be `relative` or at least not `static`, `height` should be not in `%` if no any parents with exact height declared.

Comment: That disables scrolling for every other element and I have other content that must not be affected. Perhaps I can create a wrapper? I have tried with 100% width/height div but it doesn't remove the overflow: https://codepen.io/imaginfox/pen/RMMxOp